# Cannot access 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' which is a supertype of 'com.ex.app.MainActivity'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I create a new flutter project in android studio then "open project" the android part of it, I met
 an error in MainActivity.kt however it builds successfully.

[image]

My class pathes are:

[image]

and finally my dependencies are:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.70"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I face same Problem, now it solved in my case

Step 1 : open your project in AndroidStudio
Step 2 : open Terminal and goto your project path in terminal 
Step 3 : Hit this command  '**git clean -xfd**'
Step 3 : Goto :  File -> Invalidate caches/restart

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean
-x: ... This allows removing all untracked files, including build products...
-f: ... git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless given -f or -i...
-d: ... Specify -d to have it recurse into such directories as well...

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the flutter directory

```
rm -rf bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android*
```

Then go to project directory

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Also you can "Invalidate caches and restart" in Android Studio.

Comment: i just hit `git clean -xfd` + "Invalidate caches and restart" and `flutter pub get` after it got back up and it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and was trying to debug for ages.  The simple solution was to go to " **File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart** ".

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the beta feature "Enable code completion, navigation, etc. for Java / Kotlin" at: Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter (bottom).

Answer (score 0):

As it seems it has some problems with androidx libraries! I backed from androidx and it works without error in kotlin and java both.

Comment: You backed to what?

Comment: I mean when I backed from androidx, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade from Android Studio's Kotlin plugin from 1.3.70 to 1.3.61 solved the problem for me