# flutter project showing error in kotlin MainActivity also AndroidManifest.xml file has three errors

Tags: kotlin, android-activity

[image]

I make a flutter project in the android studio and as soon as I looked into the `androidmanifest.xml` file it showed error `MainActivity must extend android.app.Activity` even though I am not facing any issues in building a project but as I try to add the permission in `androidManifest.xml` it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
basically it can be fixed with a git command in your terminal...

```
git clean -xfd
```

so that's
-f to force untracked file deletion
-d to remove untracked directories
-x to remove untracked .gitignore files

It's possible you'll need to reconfigure your flutter and dart sdk paths, update your dependecies (flutter pub get / flutter pub upgrade) .
Be aware of that.

I found my solution here: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648967/cannot-access-android-arch-lifecycle-lifecycleowner-which-is-a-supertype-of-c)